# Async/await - passing data to Puppeteer in a MySQL callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

I need to get every client in a table so that I can iterate through them, and use Puppeteer to crawl some data. I need the MySQL query because I gotta pass some params through the querystring.

I'm using Puppeteer, Puppeteer-cluster (due to the hundreds of rows), and MySQL driver.

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const { Cluster } = require('puppeteer-cluster');

const sql = "select an.id_clientes, ano, c.nome, c.cpf, c.dt_nasc from clientes_anos an inner join clientes c on an.id_clientes = c.id limit 3";
db.query(sql, async (err, result) => {
    //console.log(result);

    const cluster = await Cluster.launch({
        concurrency: Cluster.CONCURRENCY_CONTEXT,
        maxConcurrency: 2,
        puppeteerOptions: {
            headless: false
        },
        //monitor: true,
        timeout: 90000,
    });

    for (const elem of result){
        const cpf = elem.cpf;
        const dt = elem.dt_nasc.toLocaleDateString();

        const url = `https://servicos.receita.fazenda.gov.br/Servicos/ConsRest/Atual.app/paginas/index.asp?cpf=${cpf}&dtnasc=${dt}`;
        console.log(url);


        (async()=>{

            cluster.on('taskerror', (err, data) => {
                //console.log(`Error crawling ${data}: ${err.message}`);
            });
            
            await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: url }) => {
                console.log(dt, cpf);
                await page.goto(url);
                await page.type('#data_nascimento', dt);
                await page.type('input[name=CPF]', cpf);
                await page.waitForNavigation();

                try{
                    const msg = await page.$eval(
                    `#rfb-main-container table tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1)`, divs => divs.innerText.trim()
                    );
            
                    if(msg.includes('Resultado encontrado: Saldo inexistente de imposto a pagar ou a restituir.')){
                        console.log('situação: '+ msg);
                    }else{
                        console.log('0');
                    }
            
                }catch(exception){
                    console.log('Error');
                }

            });
            
            await cluster.queue(url);
            
            await cluster.idle();
            await cluster.close();

        })();
    }

});
```

The problem I'm having is that when the page loads, `await page.type('#data_nascimento', dt); await page.type('input[name=CPF]', cpf);` are not returning the right value (the one that comes from the query is right), they are returning the value of the last row. I'm betting it's something with async but I can't figure it out.

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

damn boy, i have things to say :)

1. I think the main cause of your issue is interaction between loops / callbacks / cluster
   here is an exemple to clarify my point on loops

```
for (var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i);
  }, 1000);
}
// shows : 3 3 3
// because when console is finally executed "i" has been fully looped
```

if instead of var you had used const or let, the code would work fine and show 0 1 2.

if you dont use callbacks but only awaits this situation would be much clearer.

```
async function wait(ms) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(resolve, ms);
  });
}

for (var i = 0; i<3; i++) {
  await wait(1000);
  console.log(i);
}
```

you can appply this to you mysql call to flatten your code.

```
function query(sql) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.query(sql, function(err, result) {
      if (err) return reject(err);

      resolve(result);
    })
  });
}

//then you call it like this
const sql = "select an.id_clientes, ano, c.nome, c.cpf, c.dt_nasc from clientes_anos an inner join clientes c on an.id_clientes = c.id limit 3";
const result = await query(sql)
```

2. in this spirit of flatenning your code, can you remove the async autoexecuting function ? It looks very unnecessary.
   "(async()=>{"
   ...
   "})();"
3. and finally the cluster part : its not written, but from reading the documentation i guess that any data you want to use in the cluster function needs to be pushed in the queue (the XXX).

```
cluster.queue(XXX)
=> 
await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: XXX}) ...)
```

you should then push not only your url but a whole object if you need many different data.

```
cluster.queue({cpf, dt, url})
=> 
await cluster.task(async ({ page, data: {cpf, dt, url}}) ...)
```

i never tried using this module, but it makes sens to me.
can you try it ?

PS: Also, not using cluster at all could greatly simplify things.

Comment: Awesome! It solved that issue and got me close to where I wanted. The problem I'm facing now is a `(node:10012) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected.`. I thought queueing with Puppeteer-cluster would avoid the memory issue, since it would wait for one to finish so it could start another page. At least that was what I thought. How could it simplify? Keep in mind that I have almost a thousand rows to iterate.

Comment: Cluster.on and cluster.task should not be declared in the loop. Put them just before for exemple.

Comment: Same goes for cluster.close :)You should not close the cluster on each loop iteration.

Comment: Oh, of course. I'm stupid. Never realized that being in the loop was a problem. You're a life saver, thank you so much!